# iPhone application error. NSString with whitespace

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, whitespace

I am having a major problem with my iPhone app. My problem seems basic but I cannot find out the reason for the error. I have a NSString saveDescription that is set by user's input.

```
 savede = civilsJobDescTb.text;
```

I then call in a NSLog to check the string has been set, and it is. So I have no problem there.

Later in the program I create a PDF file with several details. Everything works ok except the NSString that I have set earlier. It seem as if the string no longer exists. I get an error from it. `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` or something like that.

Now for the weird thing. This only happens when I have a whitespace in the text box. Eg: I enter "ok" and it will work without problem. But if I enter "Everything is ok" then I get errors.

I can't see where the problem is. Any ideas?

Comment: Will be difficult to help without any actual code.

Comment: I know what you mean, But I can't post all of the code. If I knew where the problem was then I could post that section. Basically Im just wondering if there is some memory management problem that resets or wipes a NSString?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't specify if your "`savede`" is an ivar (instance variable) but assuming that it is,

***and if you are using ARC***, set a strong property to it:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString * savede;

self.savede = civilsJobDescTb.text;
```

***If you are not using ARC***, then make sure to retain your "`savede`" string after setting it.  Something like:

```
 savede = civilsJobDescTb.text;
 [savede retain];
```

(making sure to release it when you are truly finished with it).

You can also make a copy of the string (in case the label that it's coming from disappears, or is cleared, or somehow disappears).

```
[savede setString: civilsJobDescTb.text];
[savde retain];
```

Comment: you can also copy the string using `saved = [civilsJobDescTb.text copy];`

Comment: Perfect, It works now. It seems [savede retain]; is what I was missing. Thanks.